# How to compile C/C++ code in Android Studio without AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: c++, c, android-studio

I really like using the JetBrains IDEs such as IntellIJ and Android Studio.   I have a C/C++ program that I'd like to compile and work on that isn't for Android.  For whatever reason, I can not use CLion for this project.

I noticed that Android Studio has C/C++ support for building native apps.  I can create a New app and get it to build my code fine, but it's really annoying that you have to set up your project a certain way so that it can find things like `src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`, which I don't care about since this isn't for Android.

Is there anyway to use AS to compile C/C++ programs without having to add all of the cruft that the gradle plugin is looking for?

Comment: Can't help you, but I came here to do a routine removal of "C" or "C++" from the tag list, and I give you props for actually finding a question for which both are relevant.

Comment: I don't know either, but I would imagine that Android Studio is strongly biased towards compiling C and C++ for Android. It isn't just a matter of compiling the code, but of integrating it into an Android project, and perhaps building the same source into libraries for different CPU architectures. It doesn't surprise me that it needs to know something about the Android project, and assume that there is one. Good luck :)